# association owned by classifier and association owned by relationship in UML

Tags: associations, uml, relationship, classification

7.3.3  Association(from kernel) ,page 36,UML superstructure ,v2.4.1:

## an association either owned  by classifier or by relationship.

Is there a real-life example in UML about association owned by classifier and association owned by relationship?

Comment: Do you mean a *property* owned by an association vs. one owned by a class?

Comment: thanks to you @JimL.
your question raised another question
I have some confusion because in UML specification the generalization of association relationship is either classifier or relationship but in tool that I use which is Papyrus the  owner of property(member end) is either classifier or association as you can see in the following screen shot
http://ge.tt/1hXG8Js/v/0?c

and I do know that there is difference between association and association end

Comment: Class Association is a specialization of both Classifier and Relationship (i.e. multiple inheritance).  There is no '**or**' here, nor does either class Classifier or class Relationship own class Association.
An **instance** of class Association has an owner (because it is an Element).  It also has associations to two or more Properties which themselves have owners.
Interestingly, Element::owner is a derived union.  Looking at the UML spec, I can't actually find any properties of Association that subset owner.  So how then can an Association have an owner? Different problem though...

Answer (score 4):

Chriss

I hope this simple example helps.

Guess you have a Java class

```
public class A {
   private B b;
   ...
}
```

In UML you would model this relationship as an association from A to B:

A -> B

with the following modeling elements:

```
Class B
Class A
  + Property b : B [0..1]    (owned by the class)
Association A_to_B
  + Property from_a : A [1]  (owned by the association)
```

Where the association A_to_B would have 2 association (member) ends referring two the properties showed above (A::b and A_to_B::from_a):

Now, let's think the following situation

```
public class A {
   private B b;
   ...
}
public class B {
   private A a;
   ...
}
```

In UML, you could the model the association (navigable in both ways) between A and B:

A <-> B

Whose model elements would be:

```
Class B
  + Property a : A [0..1]  (owned by the class)
Class A
  + Property b : B [0..1]  (owned by the class)
Association A_B
```

Where the association A_B would have 2 association (member) ends referring the two the properties showed above (A::b and B::a).

Comment: Hi @ASBH ! thank you for helpful answer. What is the relation between the `owner of association end` and `navigable` ?because I  have also noticed that if the owner is set to association, then the navigable will automatically set to False .
 if the owner is set to classifier, then the navigable will set to True . (but I don't know Why Owner and Navigable work together?)
Please,see my diagrams of your above example in both cases (using Papyrus). is this what you are trying to say?

http://postimg.org/image/z4frjeysf/

Comment: @Andrew, Have a look to UML 2.5 section 6.4.2: "Arrow notation is used to denote association end navigability. By definition, all class-owned association ends are navigable. By convention, all association-owned ends in the metamodel are not navigable"

Comment: Since I also struggled with what association end ownership really means, I came across this question - and during my search also found an OMG document which I think explains the matter quite nicely: [Getting it Right on the Dot](https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

- Before other things you should understand what the association A to B is.

  - Basically it is a solid line between A and B. It can represent one structure that connects class/instanc(es) of A with the class/instances of B. The structure can be of any sort and belong anywhere. All information, written about the line, describes this structure.
  - If there are two structures, one structure, that connects one instance of A with instance(s) of B and another structure that connects instance of B with instance(s) of A, you can show them both in ONE association. Then, information written about its B end describes the first structure (b->a) and info about the other end describes the other structure.
  - If you'll have more than one structure guiding from A to B, you have to draw two different associations.
  - If a joining structure is complex, you could represent it as an Association Class. There you can define more details.
  - A joining structure can connect more than two classes, then it will be shown as a large diamond with solid branches to these classes. It is still association! Attention: these two more complex associations are very badly supported by existing tools. You can easily create something absolutely senseless with them. And they are difficult. Use carefully.

---

[image: example Class diagram]

---

In C++ instance A can have the B instance not by pointer, but directly. There is NO special UML sign for it, it should be shown in the same way as normal, pointer attribute.