# Reverse engineering to class diagram weird associations

Tags: visual-paradigm

I am trying to reverse-engineer a school project into a Class Diagram. I noticed that when it's done, all my associations have this little bullet kind of thing in front of the one-way navigable arrow like this:

[image]

What is it and what does it do? Also how do I turn it on or off, or get rid of it?

I would greatly appreciate your help as I cannot find any relevant information on Google and it is due tomorrow to finish it.

Comment: My guess is that it means that there is no arrow in the other direction. How to get rid of it: erase them in paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! :D

For some magical reason stackoverflow gave this in related questions: [setting the association-end ownership in uml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932674/setting-the-association-end-ownership-in-uml-what-does-it-mean-with-respect-to?rq=1)

I didn't know how to describe what I was looking for, ownership is what it is! :)