# aggregation/composition vs directional aggregation/composition?

Tags: c++, uml, diagram

what is the difference between aggregation/composition and directional aggregation/composition in bouml?

directional aggregation/composition concepts are not found elsewhere except bouml and bouml does not explain in its site.

note: Code based explanations would be much better.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967841/aggregation-vs-composition-vs-association-vs-direct-association

Comment: @Sumeet it's not a duplicate: the other question is about the difference between different types of association.  Here it is about a property (unidirectional/bidirectional)  that exists for each association (navigability)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the wording used by the [site](http://www.bouml.fr/doc/relation.html) of the BOUML UML toolbox,  "directional" has to be understood as "unidirectional" (opposed to "bidirectional") :

> aggregation : to define a bi-directional aggregation, the code
>   generators will produce two attributes whose names are the roles's
>   name. This kind of relation may considered to be a shortcut to define
>   two (directional) aggregations.

This "directional" term refers hence to navigation possibility between the related objects.  For comparison, in MSVC2015 you find the notion of direction in the "Is Navigable" [property of the association](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323862.aspx).

The unidirectional aggregation could therefore be for example:

```
class Member { ... };  // member of a club 
class Club {
   list<Members*> members; // you can go from Club to Members but not the contrary. 
   ...
};
```

The bidirectional aggregation should then be something like:

```
class Club; 
class Member {   // member of a club 
    list<Club*> clubs;  // club to which a membershib relation exist.  
    ...
};
class Club {
   list<Members*> members; // you can go from Club to Members and now back. 
   ...
};
```

For undirectional composition, we could have for example:

```
class Element { ... };  // Elemetn doesn't know parent (=> unidirectional)
class Object {
    vector<Element> element; // own by value for example
    ...
};
```

Or:

```
class Element { ... }; 
class Object {
    vector<unique_ptr<Element>> element; // ownnership by unique pointer 
    ...
};
```

Bidirectional composition could then be something like:

```
class Object; 
class Element {
    Object *parent;    //  you can navigate back (Element knows about parent)
    ...
 }; 
class Object {
    vector<Element> element; // own by value for example
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Christophe is right. Does this means that "directional" is a bad choice and it would be preferable to replace "directional" by "unidirectional" ?

**Edit: some additional elements about terminolgy for the records**

The [UML standard v2.5](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/) from OMG defines in section *11.5.Associations* the principle of navigability:

> Navigability means that instances participating in links at runtime
>   (instances of an Association) can be accessed efficiently from
>   instances at the other ends of the Association. The precise mechanism
>   by which such efficient access is achieved is implementation specific.
>   If an end is not navigable, access from the other ends may or may not
>   be possible, and if it is, it might not be efficient.

The following wordings support the term "directional":

- "*The arrow indicates that the Association is to be read as associating the end away from the direction of the arrow with the end to which the arrow is pointing*"
- "*Associations with navigability in both directions*"
- "*has no **directional** significance*" (in section 20.1.4 about another kind of diagram).

Nevertheless, in many places, the standard uses explicitely "unidirectional" and "bidrectional":

- "*In a diagram where arrows are
  only shown for one-way navigable associations, this probably signifies bidirectional navigability*"
- "*These diagrams (...) may show navigability (by an open arrowhead) or nonnavigability (by an X) either always, only for unidirectional associations (oneWay), or never*" (section B.3.2 about structure diagrams)
- and many other places

So, while "directional" is perfectly valid,  the term "unidrectional" may be a better an less ambiguous option.

Comment: I guess from your name and firm affirmation that you are the author of BOUML.  SO thank you very much for your confirmation !  I've edited your remark in order to provide terminological arguments for the two alternatives you've suggested. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I am the author of Bouml ;-)