# UML Class Diagrams: Relations with elements of a collection

Tags: uml, aggregation

Assume that:

- Class A has a collection of Class B (aggregation/composition)
- Class C accesses the interface of Class A to obtain specific instances of Class B
- Class C manipulates/uses the interface of Class B instances it gets

It follows that without a doubt, Class C has a relation with Class A. However one question remains: Should a relation be mapped from class C to class B, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should have the usual association (arrow) from C to B. Because having association means C have navigation from C to B.

As C can manipulate with B instances, the navigation from C to B also exists, and the back arrow is also necessary.

As the association works both-side, both arrows should not be shown. The contemporary UML standard does not use drawing of two-sided arrows.

If C has also fields (not local variables!) of type B, the C-B line should have the point on the B end. The same for the back direction. Look for examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550923/715269)

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! Kudo for the extra source too!